# Error writing to a text file using fwrite and file_put_contents

Tags: php

I'm pretty new at using fwrite and file_put_contents and am getting errors on every line of my for loop statement:

```
Warning: file_put_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string,
```

or

```
Warning: fwrite(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in...
```

This is the code:

> $databank = "data.txt";   $access = fopen($databank, 'w')or die("cant
>   open file");  fclose($access);

```
$row = "$ent1".' | '."$ent2".' | '."$perc1a".'% | '."$perc1a_frac".'% | '."$frac1a".' | '."$perc2a".'% | '."$perc2a_frac".'%  | '."$frac2a".' | +'."$a".' | '."$new_ent1".' | '."$perc1b".'% | '."$perc1b_frac".'% | '."$frac1b".' | '."$perc2b".'% | '."$perc2b_frac".'% | '."$frac2b".' \n';
            fwrite($access, $row);
            //file_put_contents($access,$row);
```

I have a hunch its a string related issue. Any pointers in greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all I'd say you should understand those error messages. Not just replace the function name with another one as a form of guessing. The [error reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456) might be helpful for that.

Comment: what's in $access variable for file_put_contents ...? should be the name of file to which you are putting the contents...!

Comment: @Sudhir: That is part of the error message. It's the number 3.

Comment: i've added to show where $access is declared...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is extremely good practice **to read a manual page** before using some function. I myself always follow it, no exceptions.

Say, from one for [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) you can learn 2 things:

1. `$access` should be a **filename**.
2. to make it write many lines in a loop, special flag have to be used or file will be constantly overwritten with the last line

Answer (score 1):

### #1. Error:

> Warning: file_put_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string

In [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), it say's that first parameter is `string $filename` and explanation for that: `Path to the file where to write the data.`.

Example of use:

```
$file = 'people.txt';
$current = "John Smith\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

### #2. Error:

> Warning: fwrite(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in...

Again, in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) it say's that the first parameter is `resource $handle` and wxplanation for that: `A file system pointer resource that is typically created using fopen().`.

Example of use:

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, '1');
fwrite($fp, '23');
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

using [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), you should have following:

`$access` -- should be a filename, and since as per your question you are using it inside loop, so you should use `FILE_APPEND` in order to append the new content, like:

```
$access = "some_filename.txt";
file_put_contents($access, $yourDataHere, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
//LOCK_EX prevents anyone else writing to the file at the same time
```

**Better, read the docs for the function you are going to use.**

Answer (score 0):

I actually overlooked the

```
fclose($access);
```

I placed it before the fwrite() when it should be after. Its all ok now.